# Send form to Contact Forms 7 from external site

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7, wordpress-rest-api

I have a contact form on an external site and are trying to push the submissions to the contact forms 7 plugin in a wordpress site. I have managed to get it to work with a standard html form, but I want to submit it with ajax and load a error or success message below the send-button.

Working and lands on a successful json response from Contact Forms 7:

```
<form action="https://example.com/wp-json/contact-form-7/v1/contact-forms/256/feedback" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 mt-3">

<div class="row g-3">
  <div class="col-12">
    <label for="your-name" class="form-label">Fullt navn</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="your-name" name="your-name">
  </div>
  <div class="col-12">
    <label for="your-email" class="form-label">E-postadresse</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="your-email" name="your-email">
  </div>
  <div class="col-12">
    <label for="Firma" class="form-label">Firma</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firma">
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <label for="zip" class="form-label">Postnummer</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="zip">
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    <label for="city" class="form-label">Sted</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="city">
  </div>

</div>

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 mt-3">
  <div class="col-12">
    <label for="your-subject" class="form-label">Henvendelsen gjelder</label>
    <select id="your-subject" name="your-subject" class="form-select">
      <option selected>Choose...</option>
      <option>...</option>
    </select>
  </div>

<div class="form-floating mt-4">
  <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Skriv din melding her" id="your-message" style="height: 170px"></textarea>
  <label for="your-message">Melding</label>
</div>

  <div class="col-12 mt-4">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-dark">Send</button>
  </div>

    </div>
        </div>
</form>
```

This is what I have tried for ajax solution:

In header:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".bin").click(function () {
var datastring = $("#Form").serialize();
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
enctype: "multipart/form-data",
url: "https://https://example.com/wp-json/contact-form-7/v1/contact-forms/256/feedback",
data: datastring,
dataType: "json",
success: function (data) {
var obj = JSON.stringify(data);
$(".result").append(
'</textarea></li><li class="list-group-item active">Result</li><li class="list-group-item">Name: ' +
data["form"]["name"] +
'</li><li class="list-group-item">Email: ' +
data["form"]["email"] +
'</li><li class="list-group-item">Gender: ' +
data["form"]["multiple"] +
'</li><li class="list-group-item">Comments: ' +
data["form"]["text"] +
"</li></ul></div>"
);
},
error: function () {
$(".result").append("Error occured");
},
});
});
});
</script>
```

Html:

```
<form id="Form">

        <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 mt-3">

<div class="row g-3">
  <div class="col-12">
    <label for="your-name" class="form-label">Fullt navn</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="your-name" name="your-name">
  </div>
  <div class="col-12">
    <label for="your-email" class="form-label">E-postadresse</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="your-email" name="your-email">
  </div>
  <div class="col-12">
    <label for="Firma" class="form-label">Firma</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firma">
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <label for="zip" class="form-label">Postnummer</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="zip">
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    <label for="city" class="form-label">Sted</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="city">
  </div>

</div>

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 mt-3">
  <div class="col-12">
    <label for="your-subject" class="form-label">Henvendelsen gjelder</label>
    <select id="your-subject" name="your-subject" class="form-select">
      <option selected>Choose...</option>
      <option>...</option>
    </select>
  </div>

<div class="form-floating mt-4">
  <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Skriv din melding her" id="your-message" style="height: 170px"></textarea>
  <label for="your-message">Melding</label>
</div>

  <div class="col-12 mt-4">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark bin">Send</button>
  </div>

    </div>
        </div>
</form>
<div class="result"></div>
```

I have tried the above described, but only get the error occured as response from the form.

UPDATE: I have tried some more and successfully sending messages with the approach below. But now I only need to insert the "message" response from the api below the submit button. As for now I only get "[object Object]" as output from the json-response that looks like this:

```
{
    "contact_form_id": 256,
    "status": "mail_sent",
    "message": "Takk for din melding. Den har nå blitt sendt.",
    "posted_data_hash": "551bea1f0cbe640218909efcf2f68a32",
    "into": "#",
    "invalid_fields": []
}
```

FORM:

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="my-form">

        <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 mt-3">

<div class="row g-3">
  <div class="col-12">
    <label for="your-name" class="form-label">Fullt navn</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="your-name" name="your-name" required>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12">
    <label for="your-email" class="form-label">E-postadresse</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="your-email" name="your-email" required>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12">
    <label for="Firma" class="form-label">Firma</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="your-company" name="your-company" required>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <label for="zip" class="form-label">Postnummer</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="your-zip" name="your-zip" required>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    <label for="city" class="form-label">Sted</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="your-city" name="your-city" required>
  </div>

</div>

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 mt-3">
  <div class="col-12">
    <label for="your-subject" class="form-label">Henvendelsen gjelder</label>
    <select id="your-subject" name="your-subject" class="form-select">
      <option selected>Choose...</option>
      <option>...</option>
    </select>
  </div>

<div class="form-floating mt-4">
  <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Skriv din melding her" id="your-message" name="your-message" style="height: 170px"></textarea>
  <label for="your-message">Melding</label>
</div>

  <div class="col-12 mt-4">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-dark" id="btnSubmit">Send</button>
  </div>

    </div>
        </div>
</form>
    <span id="output"></span>
```

SCRIPT:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnSubmit").click(function (event) {
            //stop submit the form, we will post it manually.
            event.preventDefault();
     
            // Get form
            var form = $('#my-form')[0];
     
            // FormData object 
            var data = new FormData(form);
     
            // If you want to add an extra field for the FormData
            data.append("CustomField", "This is some extra data, testing");
     
            // disabled the submit button
            $("#btnSubmit").prop("disabled", true);
     
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
                url: "https://example.com/wp-json/contact-form-7/v1/contact-forms/256/feedback",
                data: data,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                cache: false,
                timeout: 800000,
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#output").text(data);
                    console.log("SUCCESS : ", data);
                    $("#btnSubmit").prop("disabled", true);
                },
                error: function (e) {
                    $("#output").text(e.responseText);
                    console.log("ERROR : ", e);
                    $("#btnSubmit").prop("disabled", false);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it:

HTML:

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="my-form">

        <div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6 mt-3">

<div class="row g-3">   <div class="col-12">
    <label for="your-name" class="form-label">Fullt navn</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="your-name" name="your-name" required>
    <div class="invalid-feedback">
      Please enter a message in the textarea.
    </div>   </div>   <div class="col-12">
    <label for="your-email" class="form-label">E-postadresse</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="your-email" name="your-email" required>   </div>   <div class="col-12">
    <label for="Firma" class="form-label">Firma</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="your-company" name="your-company" required>   </div>   <div class="col-sm-4">
    <label for="zip" class="form-label">Postnummer</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="your-zip" name="your-zip" required>   </div>   <div class="col-sm-8">
    <label for="city" class="form-label">Sted</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="your-city" name="your-city" required>   </div>

</div>

    </div>  <div class="col-md-6 mt-3">   <div class="col-12">
    <label for="your-subject" class="form-label">Henvendelsen gjelder</label>
    <select id="your-subject" name="your-subject" class="form-select" required>
      <option selected>Velg...</option>
      <option>...</option>
    </select>   </div>

<div class="form-floating mt-4">   <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Skriv din melding her" id="your-message" name="your-message" style="height: 170px"></textarea>   <label for="your-message">Melding</label> </div>

  <div class="col-12 mt-4">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-dark" id="btnSubmit">Send</button>   </div>

    </div>      </div> </form>
    <span class="" id="output"></span>
```

SCRIPT in footer:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#my-form").submit(function (event) {
            //stop submit the form, we will post it manually.
            event.preventDefault();
     
            // Get form
            var form = $('#my-form')[0];
     
            // FormData object 
            var data = new FormData(form);
     
            // If you want to add an extra field for the FormData
            data.append("CustomField", "This is some extra data, testing");
     
            // disabled the submit button
            $("#btnSubmit").prop("disabled", true);
     
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
                url: "https://fsenergi-admin.webdemo.no/wp-json/contact-form-7/v1/contact-forms/256/feedback",
                data: data,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                cache: false,
                timeout: 800000,
                success: function (data) {
        $('#output').addClass('mt-4 p-3 bg-white d-block fw-bold');
                    $("#output").text(data.message);
                    console.log("SUCCESS : ", data);
                    $("#btnSubmit").prop("disabled", false);
                },
                error: function (e) {
                    $("#output").text(e.responseText);
                    console.log("ERROR : ", e);
                    $("#btnSubmit").prop("disabled", false);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```